# Products Not Showing on Front End

Tags: product, frontend, custom-options, category-products

I have had this problem for some time now, I import new products using MAGMI and after re-indexing and cache clearing the products do not display on the front end in the respective category pages.  They products are enabled, in stock have multiple sizes and colors but they do not display.

Everything used to work fine and they would show up accordingly, I feel like I'm missing something simple but has anybody seen this problem before or know how to fix it?

Mike

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple stores, you should switch to their view in backend and check wheter or not the products are visible in store front. Maybe the importer you are using isn't fully up to date and reimporting changes the visibility store-wise.

If product visibility is not set to the corresponding setting they might not appear in your storefront.

Please also write down which Magento Version you are using.